# Selenium WebDriver can find element in Chrome but not in FireFox

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

I'm still new to working with FireFox and using the Selenium Driver. I wrote the following driver code in Java as part of a CucumberTest. I have the ChromeDriver section commented out. When I comment out the FirefoxDriver and run this using the ChromeDriver line it works as expected. However, when I try to run the exact same code swapped to the FirefoxDriver, I get to my first when statement and I get a nullPointerException at the first find element by id line. Is there a workaround?

```
@When("^User enters \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\"$")
public void user_enters_UserName_and_Password(String realUsername, String realPassword) 
        throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(realUsername + " " + realPassword); 

    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(realUsername);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(realPassword);
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
}
```

EDIT: The issue was in how I was calling the driver. I corrected how I initilzed my driver to this and it worked. Something about how I was calling it before caused it to get discarded so it was null by the time it came to this step.

```
The issue was in how I was instantiating the Firefox driver in a different file. This is what worked ' String marionetteDriverLocation = "c://Features//geckodriver.exe";
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", marionetteDriverLocation);
        //create firefox profile
          FirefoxProfile myProfile= new FirefoxProfile();
          // This will set the true value
          myProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
          //setup the driver with profile settings for security issues. 
          driver = new FirefoxDriver(myProfile);'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `NullPointerException`??? Or getting `NoSuchElementException`??

Comment: Yes it was a NullPointerException. However, my coworker found the root of the issue in the way I was instantiating the Firefox driver.